# Javascript-based, server-free CMS?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system

I remember its look but I can't find it, either here or through Google: Does someone know the name of that JavaScript-based little CMS that doesn't require a server : When you click on any article on the left-side, the article pops up before the currently-displayed articled, and shows "Close this article" and "Close all articles" links.

Thank you.

Comment: What would be the point if you can't save the changes?

Comment: The magic is that you _can_ save the contents. I'm curious to know how it's done.

Comment: @alex "Save As" (supplied by the browser) is used for saving the changes.

Comment: @bzlm Fair enough, don't know how useful that is though.

Comment: @alex I agree, it sounds more like a "notes" or "stickies" application than a wiki. Or a poor person's HTML editor. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but you have the whole TiddlyWiki family of javascript based wikis (no server needed).

http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 3):

To make the list complete, [MDWiki](http://www.mdwiki.info) is an pure 100% client-side CMS/Wiki running with Javascript in the browser. It uses Markdown as input files, supplied after the hashbang (`#!`) as part of the URL.

Disclaimer: I am somewhat biased as I am the author of it. It is free and open source licensed GPL.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure to take a look at [Instant](https://instant.cm), A javascript based content management solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are thinking about GEEKO CMS.
http://www.cms.online-business.ro/
If you are going to create a small website this might be a possible answer.
Cheers
Luca

Comment: Thanks Luca. I didn't know about Geeko CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this one http://jscms.sourceforge.net/eng/

Comment: Looks like jscms is the basis for Geeko are one and the same... perhaps jscms evolved into Geeko?

Comment: Please have a look into the sourcecode of this page.. It's not just ugly, this can not be the base of a professional application!